# Which option is correct in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar

"The people in the west have been considering (separate/separating) themselves from the rest of the country." Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Correct answer

separating

### Why?

Let's ask, "What have the people in the west been considering"?

Since we're looking for "what" (not where, why, etc.), we need a noun to answer that question.

So in this case, we need a noun form of "separate". "Separate" has a noun form--its gerund--which is "separating".

### Side note

Another noun form of "separate" is "separation". In this case, the sentence would read, "The people in the west have been considering a separation of themselves from the rest of the country." However, the sentence with "...separating themselves.." sounds more natural.